# How soon can I re-enter the USA after staying there for 60/90 days ? when does the program re-set?

Tags: visas, usa, customs-and-immigration, us-visa-waiver-program

I am travelling to the USA from england next month, after about 60 days travelling i am going to cuba for about a week, and then I'm hoping to go to cancun and from there to Hawaii, would i be able to spend another full 90 days in hawaii before having to leave, as I've previously left the US, or would it just be 30 days, to make up 90 from the time i already spent in the states?
any advice would be very much appreciated!

Comment: There isn't a formal period, but this kind of itinerary arouses suspicion as it looks like a visa run. An alternative is to get a B1/B2 visa from the US Embassy which would enable you to stay in the US for six months (180 days).  Separately, note also that it remains illegal to fly from the USA to Cuba directly for tourism purposes.

Comment: See also http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13964/how-soon-can-i-re-enter-the-usa-having-stayed-for-90-days-under-the-visa-waiver

Comment: Even if done legally, I don't think a trip to Cuba would be far enough stop the visa waiver clock, so most likely the OP, if using the visa waiver program, would have to leave Hawaii no more than 90 days after the first arrival in the US.

Comment: @Calchas ,'illegal' - only for US citizens, which the OP obviously isn't. The rest of the world _can_ travel to Cuba, directly or indirectly.

Comment: @Calchas the fact that the traveler will travel only to an "adjacent island" and "contiguous territory" seems significant enough that the duplicate you've proposed does not apply.

Comment: @Aganju directly from or to the US?

Comment: Advice: another option is to get a B-2 visa.  With B-2 status, the initial period of admission is six months.

Comment: @Aganju In fact the phrasing is illegal for "persons subject to US jurisdiction", which includes anyone for the time being in the USA (except diplomats) as well as US citizens and residents wherever in the world they are. Hence you can go to Cuba from Mexico, but not directly from the US. This is also reflected in the Treasury's official advice. See http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/87626/european-citizen-visiting-cuba-while-in-us/87634

Comment: Sure, @phoog . Who do you think flies all those direct flights from the US? Mostly Permanent Residents and some round-tripping tourists.

Comment: @Aganju Many of the tourists are US citizens. The point is that they're traveling under one of the exceptions, such as the "cultural exchange" exception, which can be a pretty thinly veiled excuse for tourism.

Answer (score 2):

There is no hard and fast rule, but in general you'll want to spend more time outside the US than inside.

Cuba and Mexico do **not** restore the clock, as stated by [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?FullText=1&SECTION=VI&COUNTRY=us&SUBSECTION=AI&ExpertMode22=&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX), and the clock will **continue** while you're in these countries.

So if you spend 60 days in the US, then 7 days in Cuba, then (for example) 3 days in Cancun, you will have 90-60-7-3=**20 days left in the US**

Comment: It's worth mentioning, however, that the non-resetting of the clock is discretionary.  Also, the traveler can escape that provision by setting foot in Belize, half a day's drive from Cancun.