# Traveling to Cuba through USA as a non-USA citizen

Tags: usa, international-travel, cuba

There exist a [couple](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/35317/us-law-and-travel-to-cuba-for-citizens-of-third-countries/35368#35368) of [other](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/87626/european-citizen-visiting-cuba-while-in-us) questions on the matter but the circumstances have changed yet again.

Currently I am in the states and will be flying from the US to Cuba in a week. Although I am a British citizen on my travels, it appears that when flying from the states to Cuba [I will be subject to US jurisdiction](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/87634/50854). Under Obamas regulations I could fly from the states to Cuba as long as met one of the [twelve travel criteria](https://cu.usembassy.gov/u-s-citizen-services/local-resources-of-u-s-citizens/traveling-to-cuba/).

I have an itinerary comprised of educational activities and am traveling alone using a standard American airline. I will be staying in private airbnbs. I will be returning to the US after Cuba.

However, President Trump has apparently made changes which will affect future travel. I can't find much information on the changes but it seems at least [two of the twelve criteria](http://www.rollingstone.com/politics/features/traveling-to-cuba-under-trump-policy-what-you-need-to-know-w488649) will be removed - including educational activities. Another [source](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/06/12/travel/cuba-travel-tips-trump-administration.html?mcubz=0) claims that if the travel plans have been made before the travel changes come into effect, my trip should be ok.

All that said, I can only find *when* the [travel changes were announced](http://legalcubatravel.com/) (June 16th?) - not whether they have actually come into effect yet. Can anyone confirm if these changes have come into effect yet?

Comment: Not an answer, but the normal way to do this is to travel through another country such as Canada or Mexico.

Comment: Entire trip is already booked

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These changes have not yet come into effect because OFAC (the Office of Foreign Asset Controls) has yet to publish new regulations.

Further, OFAC has said its new regulations will still permit travel that was at least partially booked before the President's announcement if said travel would have been valid under the old regulations.

I suggest you finalize your arrangements before the new regulations are published, as it appears you may not be able to complete any bookings after this date.

See Question 5 at [Frequently Asked Questions on President Trump’s Cuba Announcement](https://www.treasury.gov/resource-center/sanctions/Programs/Documents/cuba_faqs_20170725.pdf) published by the US Treasury.

> **5. How do the changes announced by the President on June 16, 2017 affect individual people-to-people travelers who have already begun making their travel
>   arrangements (such as purchasing flights, hotels, or rental cars)?**
>
> The announced changes do not take effect until OFAC issues new regulations. Provided that the traveler has already completed at least one travel-related transaction (such as purchasing a flight or reserving accommodation) prior to the President’s announcement on June 16, 2017, all additional travel-related transactions for that trip would also be authorized, including if the trip occurs after OFAC issues new regulations, provided the travel-related transactions are consistent with OFAC’s regulations as of June 16, 2017.
>   Once the State Department publishes its list of entities and subentities with which direct transactions will not be authorized and OFAC issues its regulations, no new transactions may be initiated with these identified entities and subentities. Prior travel arrangements that may involve these entities or subentities will still be authorized. See FAQ 8.

The US Treasury is responsible for the Office of Foreign Asset Controls so I would regard this information as authoritative.